# Does .Net core 2.0 supports Apache NMS Active MQ packages?

Tags: c#, apache-nms

Warning NU1701  Package 'Apache.NMS 1.7.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested `Apache.NMS` and `Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ` DLLs from nuget packages with [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer), it said they are 100% compatible with: ".NET Core,.NET Framework,.NET Standard". I also tested it in simple scenarios like linux .net core app writing to queue, it worked. So i'd say they are functional, but can't be sure to what degree.

We use it in production for about half a year, no issues. We only do posting messages to MQ though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this packages for `.NET Core`

- [`Apache.NMS.NetCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apache.NMS.NetCore/)
- [`Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.NetCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.NetCore/)

Comment: Still the second link provides the right answer: yes it supports Apache active mq packages

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for now that you can do that, sorry, another alternative is to take classes that consume ActiveMQ by REST, http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html 
and do not use these dlls.